# How to join two dataframes with datetime index while preserving only the data at the same period?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have different DataFrames of the following format:

```
     Date   X     Y    Value            Customer
 2015-05-29 12:00:00   1.0   4.0  3.340            13458 
 2015-05-29 12:15:00   1.0   4.0  3.448            13458 
 2015-05-29 12:30:00   1.0   4.0  3.145            13458
 2015-05-29 12:45:00   1.0   4.0  3.535            13458 
 2015-05-29 13:15:00   1.0   4.0  3.299            13458 
 2015-05-29 13:30:00   1.0   4.0  3.193            13458 
 2015-05-29 13:45:00   1.0   4.0  3.560            13458
```

However, the records are of different periods, but them full overlap to some extent. I want to join while preserving only the data of the overlapping periods. I have tried to join, merge, concat; it works for the `how='outer'` but not for the option `inner`. 
For examplo, for the code, after `df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)`:

```
df = pd.merge(df,aux, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

and

```
df = df.join(aux, how='inner', lsuffix='_x', rsuffix='_y')
```

I get the same empty Dataframe:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [X_x, Y_x, value_x, customer_x, X_y, Y_y, value_y, customer_y]
Index: []
```

And finally for the code:

```
df = pd.concat([df, aux], axis=1, join='inner')
```

I get:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain what is your overlap like? Is it day overlap? Also, when you said it works for 'outer', did you get the right match?

Comment: Did you `df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)` for both DataFrames before merging?  If not, do so.

Comment: @GokulKrishnanR they overlap completely, as I just edited above.

Comment: @Trenton_M I've already done it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try the following approach. I think the problem could be with the indexes. It should give the desired output.

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B"], data=[['2015-05-29 12:00:00',0],['2015-05-29 12:15:00',1],['2015-05-29 12:30:00',2]])
df1['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['A'])
df1.set_index(['A'],inplace= True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["C", "D"], data=[['2015-05-29 12:00:00',3],['2015-05-29 12:15:00',4],['2015-05-29 12:30:00',5]])
df1['C'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['C'])
df2.set_index(['C'],inplace= True)

df = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've alreary tried it, but it didn't work. I'm using `df.dropna()` after join them `how='outer'`, which I think is not the most elegant and safe way of doing it.